# How to disable colors in Jest output

Tags: jestjs

When I run Jest in a terminal with a light background, its yellow output is totally unreadable.

I have tried to find any options that allow me to customize the colors, or turn off output coloring altogether. I found plenty of suggestions with `--colors` to turn output colors *on* but that is the opposite of what I need.

I am using Linux with an xterm window, with black text on a white background.

Answer (score 11):

For version `"jest": "^24.8.0",` use `jest --no-colors` command to disable the colors of test output.